# Image quality lowers when drawing bitmap on a smaller size canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

How can I preserve the bitmap image quality when drawing on a canvas of a smaller size? Right now, the resulting bitmap (on the left) is a bit grainy, while the original bitmap is of good quality (on the right).

[image]

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1024, 1024, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

canvas.drawBitmap(userPic, null, new Rect(0, 0, imageWidthPx, 1024), paint);
```

The original image is larger, so it shouldn't lose details. I'm drawing it with preserved aspect ratio.

Comment: Please mention all resolutions.

Comment: @blackapps Original bitmap size is 2000x1200, scaled down to 1024x614

Comment: At scaling down it looses details. Imagine you scale down from 1000x1000 to 10x10. Will it loose?